# Java streams: group and sort by a previous mapping result?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have to following code:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class TimeZonesExample
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Set<String> allZones = ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds();
        LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();

        List<String> zoneList = new ArrayList<>(allZones);

        for (String s : zoneList)
        {
            ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of(s);
            ZonedDateTime zoneDateTime = localDateTime.atZone(zoneId);
            ZoneOffset zoneOffset = zoneDateTime.getOffset();
            String out = String.format("%35s %10s%n", zoneId, zoneOffset);

            System.out.printf(out);
        }
    }
}
```

This produces such a list:

```
                  Asia/Aden     +03:00
             America/Cuiaba     -03:00
                  Etc/GMT+9     -09:00
                  Etc/GMT+8     -08:00
             Africa/Nairobi     +03:00
            America/Marigot     -04:00
                 Asia/Aqtau     +05:00
          Pacific/Kwajalein     +12:00
        America/El_Salvador     -06:00
             Asia/Pontianak     +07:00
               Africa/Cairo     +02:00
          Pacific/Pago_Pago     -11:00
             Africa/Mbabane     +02:00
               Asia/Kuching     +08:00
                               ....
```

Instead of the for loop and to get more familiar with stream API, I tried to rewrite this to a stream result whereby the result should be sorted by the offset. The result should look like this:

```
-09:00 Etc/GMT+9   
-08:00 Etc/GMT+8    
-04:00 America/Marigot     
-03:00 America/Cuiaba
+03:00 Africa/Nairobi     
+03:00 Asia/Aden
```

I was able to print the offsets (unsorted) with the expression below, but how to apply them on the zoneIds? I somehow have to remember the previous zoneId mapping result.

```
allZones.stream()
    .map(s -> ZoneId.of(s))
    .map(zId -> localDateTime.atZone(zId).getOffset())
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: If you insert `.sorted()` just before `.forEach()`, will the program do what you want? I am not sure I grasp the expectations here.

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen This will sort in ascending order but this does not solve the problem how to map them together with the zoneIds.

Comment: Just to be clear, you're asking two questions, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't reach back into the previous step of the stream to get the element before the current step.

To sort the stream you must provide a way to sort the strings using a Comparator.

Converting your code to apply `sorted()`, this produces the output you want:

```
allZones.stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.<String, ZoneOffset>comparing(s -> localDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.of(s)).getOffset()).reversed())
    .map(s -> String.format("%10s %s", localDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.of(s)).getOffset(), ZoneId.of(s)))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I want. Henrik's solution is also good, but yours is a little bit better because this solution only needs one map operation.

Answer (score 5):

You can grab the `ZoneId` back from `ZonedDateTime.getZone()`. Try this out:

```
ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()
        .stream()
        .map(ZoneId::of)
        .map(ZonedDateTime::now)
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(ZonedDateTime::getOffset).reversed())
        .forEach(zdt -> System.out.println(zdt.getOffset() + "\t" + zdt.getZone()));
```

Comment: Thanks, it's much more clearer for me with method references.

Answer (score 1):

Like Piotr says, you can use [`Stream#sorted`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#sorted-java.util.Comparator-) to sort the stream.

I got something like your intended output by doing this:

```
allZones.stream()
    .map(s -> ZoneId.of(s))
    .map(zId -> localDateTime.atZone(zId))
    .sorted((o1, o2) -> o1.getOffset().getTotalSeconds() - o2.getOffset().getTotalSeconds())
    .forEach(ldt -> System.out.format("%35s %10s%n", ldt.getZone(), ldt.getOffset()));
```

Comment: Great, easier than I thought. Thanks.